# How to copy contents of a baseline in Clearcase UCM?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool, baseline

I want to copy the contents of the integration stream at a certain baseline to a directory outside CC using command line, ie. I want to "export" a baselined version to use a Subversion term. I think the way to do this is to set the view to show the contents of the baseline and perform the copy - or is my thinking wrong for Clearcase? I'm more of a SVN/Git user :)

How can I set a baseline for a snapshot view of an integration stream on command line?

I'm using Clearcase UCM in Windows environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the baseline has been created on that integration stream, you can:

- create a child stream (immediately below that integration stream)
- rebase it with any of the baselines created on the parent (integration) stream: chose the one you are after
- create an UCM snapshot view on that child stream

The content of that snapshot view will be the one of the baseline you wanted to select.

Comment: Do I have to create a new stream? Can't I just set parameters for a view that's on the int stream? BTW, thanks for a lightning-fast response!

Comment: @apa64 no, changing a baseline on an integration stream is *not* recommended (or possible once new baselines have been created). It is much safer to create a dedicated stream, and do not make any checkout/checkin on it. As long as there is no modification, you will be able to rebase that stream as many times as you need, switching from one baseline to the other, and updating your snapshot view to reflect the new content.